# Extract arrays based on positions indicated in another array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have the data below as an example:

```
import numpy as np

data=[np.array([[0.9,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.7],[0.8,0.0,0.0,0.8,0.2],
[0.9,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.3],[0.9,0.6,0.3,0.2,0.5],[0.8,0.0,0.3,0.1,0.5]]),
np.array([[0.9,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.3],[0.0,0.2,0.4,0.0,0.0],
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2,0.0],[0.5,0.0,0.3,0.6,0.8],[0.5,0.6,0.9,0.0,0.0]])]
```

and I want to extract the relevant data based on these positions below:

```
positions_non_zero=[np.array([2,3,4]),np.array([1,4])]
```

the **desired** output should be this:

```
[array([[0.9, 0. , 0.4, 0.4, 0.3],
        [0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5],
        [0.8, 0. , 0.3, 0.1, 0.5]]),
 array([[0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0. , 0. ],
        [0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0. , 0. ]])]
```

The reason is this:

[image]

The problem with my code is that only the `np.array([1,4])` is taken under consideration.

My code:

```
df_class11=[]

for n in data:
   
    def data_target(df_class_target):
       
        for z in df_class_target:

            x_classA=[n[i] for i in z]

            x_classA=np.vstack(x_classA)
        return  x_classA
    df_class11.append(data_target(positions_non_zero))
df_class11
```

Comment: A list comprehension should do it, `[arr[idx] for arr, idx in zip(data, positions_non_zero)]`.  The `zip` iterates on the `data` and `positions` list together.

Comment: Great. You should add an actual answer below so I can give you the deserved  points.Tip: Since my code contains some redundant lines you may display how the end result of the code would be with your code added.